# Why convergence of these two series is equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

In my notes I have the following:

> For $s\geq 0$, define the *Sobolev Space* $H_s$ by:
>   $$H_s := \left\{f\in L^2([0, 2\pi], \mathbb{C})\,\, : \,\, \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |k|^{2s}|\hat{f_k}|^2 <\infty\right\}$$
>   And define the Inner Product as:
>   $$(f, g)_{(s)} := \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f_k}\bar{\hat{g_k}}(1 + k^2)^s$$
>   **Note that** $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (|k|^2)^s|\hat{f_k}|^2$ **converges iff** $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (1+k^2)^s |\hat{f_k}|^2$ **converges.**

How do we show the last statement is true? From how the lecturer put it down it seems VERY obvious as if you could do it in one line, but I couldn't show this is true.

**My Attempt**

I tried as follows: Since $s\geq 0$ then clearly:
$$(1 + k^2)^s \geq (|k|^2)^s \quad \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}\quad \forall s\geq 0$$
since $k^2 = |k|^2$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore we must have:
$$(1+k^2)^s |\hat{f_k}|^2 \geq (|k|^2)^s |\hat{f_k}|^2\quad \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}\quad \forall s\geq 0$$ so that we can show the direction "$\Longleftarrow$" using the comparison test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Note the general terms of both series (which are positive) are equivalent sice
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(1+k^2)^s|\hat f_k|^2}{k^{2s}|\hat f_k|^2}=\lim_{k\to \infty}\Bigl(1+\frac1{k^2} \Bigr)^s=1.$$
Hence both series converge or both diverge.

Comment: Oh I see what you did there. That's a pretty nice spot. How did you realize you had to use this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use that $|k|\ge 1$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, so $2k^2 \ge k^2+1$.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll work on that!